# How to insert data with custom enum type from a csv into an existing PostgreSQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, enums, datagrip

I want to insert data from a csv file into an existing table on a PostgreSQL database - let's call the table `automobile`.

One of my field is a custom `enum` - let's call it `brand`.

When I try to import records from a csv file with DataGrip built-in feature I got an error message:

```
conversion failed: "Ford" to brand
```

Yet in the following screenshot we can see that the `manufacturer` column is filled with the expected string value : `Ford`.

I guess I have to explicitly cast the string as being of `brand` type but how can I do this? I don't see any options of this kind in the import options. (see below). Should I do it in the csv file directly?

[image: DataGrip CSV import option]

**Reproduction steps**

```
CREATE TYPE brand AS ENUM ('BMW', 'Renault', 'Ford');
```

You can check you have declared an `enum` type with:

```
SELECT enum_range(NULL::brand);
```

I create a dummy table with a `manufacturer` column being of type `brand`.

```
CREATE TABLE automobile (
id int,
manufacturer brand,
registration_number varchar(10),
owner varchar(50));
```

And insert some dummy records into it:

```
INSERT INTO automobile (id, manufacturer, registration_number, owner)
VALUES (1, 'BMW', 'AAA-BBB-ZR', 'John'),
       (2, 'Renault', 'CCC-BWB-PU', 'Mike');
```

Now I try to import data from a csv file by right-clicking on my table and selecting *Import data from File...*
The csv file I select for import contains the following 2 lines:

```
id, manufacturer, registration_number, owner
3,Ford,PZB-URU-LK,Jack
```

I select the right encoding option and click OK. Then an error message is generated:

```
2:3: conversion failed: "Ford" to brand
```

If I select the option *Insert inconvertible values as Null* while checking the DataGrip import option, I got a more verbose error message:

```
2:1: ERROR: column "manufacturer" is of type brand but expression is of type character varying   Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.   Position: 90
```

I tried to specify Ford::brand in my csv and reload and got the same issue.

How can I make DataGrip understand that `Ford` is a value of the `brand` `enum`?

I already checked [DataGrip documentation on Import/Export](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/importexport.html) but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: The datagrip import tool probably does more (and worse) than it should. Use the native tool *psql*, where you can easily import the file with `\copy automobile from '/path/to/myfile.csv' (format csv, header)`.

Comment: It would be useful to see what Datagrip is translating your CSV file into. This information may be available in the Postgresql log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest DataGrip version handles enum types as expected. [The issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-7012) is fixed.

[image: import]

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug! We, DataGrip team, will handle that. Expect fix in one of further minor updates.

Please, follow the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-7012